# How to open android specific default apps page programmatically?

Tags: android, android-settings

For now, i'm using the next code to open [all default apps page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dElAw.png)

```
var intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS)
startActivity(intent)
```

**How can I open a specific default apps page programmatically ?**

For example, I want to open [Caller ID & spam app page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXz0c.png) with code

Comment: I think that is not possible for now, but you can share the file to that app (if the target app accepts it).